# Removing translation textdomain

Tags: performance, translation

I am working on a plugin for myself, so, it's totally useless to load textdomain. But most of codes I copied from others are using the `__(' ','')`
I copied the codes from several plugins. So, even if I load textdomain, it's going to be useless as well,posibly slow down the performence.
My question is-- What's going to happen when WP read those `__(' ','')` without a textdomain loaded ? 
Will it become a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually been in the exact situation you're in before, all you need to do is drop the `__()`s and the `_e()`s and replace them with their first parameter, you can pretty easily do this by regex if there are a lot, and it's quick to do by hand if there aren't...I'm not sure what the performance penalty on them is, especially if they're empty, but I'm a bit of a performance hound, so it wasn't something I was going to risk.

Comment: That's a lot of job if I try to remove the textdomain signs. but if I don't remove it, I fear WP might get confused and searching around for the texdomain.

Comment: Nope, you're good to go just leaving them in. You can just regex for them using your favorite text editor, a regex along the lines of `_[_e]\([ ]?\'[^\']*\'([ ]?,[ ]?\'[^\']*\')?[ ]?\)` should get them all (I drew that up in the comment box, so don't be surprised if you needa tweak it lol)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not localizing your theme/plugin, then these functions are quite useless. Their main purpose is to search through the localization module for translated text.

To answer your question, it will not become a problem I don't believe, but is pretty useless if you are not translating your theme or plugin into a different language - but somebody else might want to if they get their hands on your plugin/theme, so it is good to include if your product is going out to the public.

See here for more info on these:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology